GT Table is having some sort of a webshot error and won't save a png
I am simply trying to save a gt table as png and get this error. Tried restarting. Tried reinstalling webshot. Seems many are having this issue.
Error in `with_random_port()`:
! Cannot find an available port. Please try again.
Caused by error in `startup()`:
! Failed to start chrome. Error:

I can save as html but this is worthless to me as I don't know how to make it an image I can actually use.
Someone recommended this but it doesn't work either
options(webshot_port = c(5000, 6000))


See if this Q & A helps.

If anyone is seeing this I found out I needed to resinstall chromote package and it worked.

please try with
install.packages("chromote")
and run again
